# Spring unable to pick Autowired implementation by profile

Tags: java, spring, maven, inversion-of-control, autowired

I'm trying to figure out how to do mock implementations in Spring using the @Autowired annotation.  I'm trying to drive this by profiles in such a way that:

1. There is a default profile which runs when no configuration is defined
2. When the test profile is specified, it will Autowire mock objects instead of the default implementations.

In pursuit of this setup, I'm running into a problem where Spring doesn't seem to be able to tell the difference between my implementations.  I'm using Tomcat/Jersey/Maven/Spring and I am not using any xml configuration.  Here is the run down of the relevant code ([viewable on my example GitHub](https://github.com/dkwestbr/autowired_example)).

**The problem**: Running this by `mvn clean tomcat7:run` and navigating to '/foo/bar' produces the following exception (full stack trace below): `No qualifying bean of type [dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGetter] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b`

I realize that the problem is Spring cannot differentiate between my two implmentations, but I'm having trouble finding how to properly declare that I want a by default, and b only when running `mvn test`.

My initializer:

```
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        context.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

        /*
        for(String profile: appContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Active profile: %s", profile));
        }
        */

        Map<String, String> filterParameters = new HashMap<>();

        // set filter parameters
        filterParameters.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example");
        filterParameters.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath", "/WEB-INF/app");
        filterParameters.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex", "/(images|css|jsp)/.*");


        SpringServlet servlet = new SpringServlet();   
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletDispatcher = context.addServlet("jersey-servlet", servlet);
        servletDispatcher.setInitParameters(filterParameters);
        servletDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servletDispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }
```

My Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    private static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:configuration.properties")
    static class Production { }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("test")
    @PropertySource("classpath:configuration.properties")
    static class Test { }
}
```

My web endpoint which has the `@Autowired` variable in question:

```
@Path("/foo")
@Component
public class WebEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private IStringGetter getTheThing;

    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getStuff() {
        System.out.println(getTheThing.getItGood());
        return String.format("<html><body>Hello - %s</body></html>", getTheThing.getItGood());
    }
}
```

My first implementation (I want this to be default):

```
@Component
public class A implements IStringGetter {

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String configValue;

    @Override
    public String getItGood() {
        return String.format("I am an A: %s", configValue);
    }

}
```

My second implementation (I only want this when running `mvn test`):

```
@Component
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class B implements IStringGetter {

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String configValue;

    @Override
    public String getItGood() {
        return String.format("I am an B: %s", configValue);
    }
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
10:22:49.136 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webEndpoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nes
ted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IString
Getter dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.WebEndpoint.getTheThing; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionExcepti
on: No qualifying bean of type [dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGetter] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:288) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[s
pring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spr
ing-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3
.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-
3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2
.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[sprin
g-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spri
ng-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE
.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.
jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEAS
E]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2
.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.37.jar:7.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.37.jar:7.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.37.jar:7.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.37.jar:7.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.37.jar:7.0.37]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [?:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGetter
 dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.WebEndpoint.getTheThing; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
 qualifying bean of type [dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGetter] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPost
Processor.java:514) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:285) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGe
tter] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:865) ~[spring-bea
ns-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans
-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPost
Processor.java:486) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:285) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 22 more
Oct 11, 2013 10:22:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webEndpoint': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nes
ted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IString
Getter dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.WebEndpoint.getTheThing; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionExcepti
on: No qualifying bean of type [dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGetter] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGetter
 dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.WebEndpoint.getTheThing; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
 qualifying bean of type [dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGetter] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPost
Processor.java:514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostPro
cessor.java:285)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dkwestbr.spring.autowired.example.IStringGe
tter] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: a,b
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:865)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPost
Processor.java:486)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@ActiveProfiles` annotation is [meant to be used for tests](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework).

> **@ActiveProfiles**
>
> A class-level annotation that is used to declare which bean definition
>   profiles should be active when loading an ApplicationContext for test
>   classes.

As for how to set the profile for component scaning, [take a look here.](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) Basically just switch `@ActiveProfiles` with `@Profile`.

Comment: That worked to get my main configuration running (`mvn clean tomcat7:run`) but now the test is showing the same stack trace, despite having the same annotations.  So I'm guessing that the @Profile makes the class only be available when I am running with the Test profile.  Is there a way to get spring to say "A has no profile, B has profile of test, so pick B because test is the current active profile"?

Comment: @Dave No there's no way to say that `A` has no profile. The `@Profile` annotation is used to state _if this profile is active, register this bean definition_, otherwise skip it. Without the annotation, you cannot stop registration (you can apply `component-scan` exclusion filters). One way to achieve what you want, is to annotate `A` with `Profile("!test")`, in which case it will only be registered if `test` is not the active profile. Read the javadoc of `@Profile`, it explains all of this in more detail.

Comment: Profile("!test") did the trick for me.Like Dave I expected Spring to just override beans from active profile on top of the 'default' one...